# Flutter web api calling XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

```
     Future<void> _getShopListAllJson() async {
try {
  final response = await http.get("http://abair.gq/db_dept_info_all.php");
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
     setState(() {
      _data = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
    });
  } else {
    print("Some error: ${response.statusCode}");
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

Please see above code flutter web api calling error xmlhttprequest

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4SKX.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkUEt.png)

Answer (score 17):

Looks like CORS is blocking it, try adding a CORS proxy in front of your URL.

Add this in front of your URL https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

```
final response = await http.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://abair.gq/db_dept_info_all.php");
```

Once you can confirm it is working it is best practice to have your own proxy so create one using this method:

https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation

Comment: Thx for your answe, it works on my project when i emulate it on crome but when i emulate it on an pixel phone it still gives no answer, i have to add that before the change only on crome the error was shown and on the pixel nothing hapend

Comment: is there is best practice to remove this error, without using this URL in front of your API endpoint ????

Comment: It really depends what your requesting - if you manage the server with the data, you can allow your origin, if your using a service - sometimes they will have a section where you can allow an IP/URL that you can accept request from